# EXEC procedure in dynamic SQL statement only does SELECTs and not INSERTs

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure, let's call it stored procedure 'B'. Stored procedure 'B' calls stored procedure 'A' which returns a resultset that needs to be inserted into a temp table within stored procedure 'B', in order to do further mutations. Because of nested inserts, I have used `OPENROWSET` (and tried `OPENQUERY` too).

Now, it seems to work great! However, next to returning a resultset, stored procedure 'A' also does INSERTS in a table. The weird thing is, when stored procedure 'A' is executed from within stored procedure 'B', stored procedure 'A' only returns the resultset, and does NO insert at all. It just seems to skip the entire `INSERT INTO` statement. I have tried putting dummy `SELECT 'test'` breakpoints before and after the INSERT, and they are executed fine! How is this possible?

This query looks like this (I changed data and columns up a bit):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #Temp (1,2,3)

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
''SQLOLEDB'',
''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF EXECUTE StoredProcedureA

@Parameter1 = '''''+@InputValue1+'''''
,@Parameter_2 =  '''''+@InputValue2+'''''
''
)'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

No errors are returned. The resultset (`SELECT statement from procedure A`) is correctly loaded into `#Temp` within procedure B. But the `INSERT` that is done within procedure A is not executed.

Does openquery/openrowset not allow INSERTS and only execute SELECT outputs? I thought, maybe its a security/rights issue? Is there any other way to workaround this issue?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using a temporary table denoted by #.
The scope of this table is ends when your nested stored procedure ends and the temporary table is dropped.

So the insert happens, the table just doesn't exist anymore.

If you create the table before starting your nested procedure you can solve this problem. You can just drop the table in you Procedure B if you really want it gone.